# material design disable dropdown using jQuery

Tags: jquery, material-design

How to disable a material design `dropdown` when click on a button using `jQuery`?

```js
$("#btnoneway").click(function(){
  $(".airportToList").prop("disabled",true); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control airportToList"></select>

<a id="btnoneway">Click</a>
```

js:

```
$.each(a.airports, function (key, value) {
            $(".airportFromList").append($('<option></option>').val(value.code).html(value.city +' , '+ value.country +'  ('+value.code+')' ));
            $(".airportToList").append($('<option></option>').val(value.code).html(value.city +' , '+ value.country +'  ('+value.code+')' ));
        });

        $('.airportFromList').change(function () {
            //alert($(this).val());
            //Code to select image based on selected car id
        });

        $('.airportToList').change(function () {
            //alert($(this).val());
            //Code to select image based on selected car id
        });
```

The above jQuery is not working. Is there any other option to do that?

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Your code working *so good* .. try find it somewhere else, such `console`

Comment: @pedram How to disable the dropdown when click on a button??

Comment: *You already have!* I said your code working fine! | See your question updated.

Answer (score 0):

checked it here, this one is working gud. i gave "attr" instead of "prop"

```js
$("#btnoneway").click(function(){
     $(".airportToList").attr("disabled","disabled"); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control airportToList"> 
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
<button id="btnoneway">click</button>
```

Comment: Dude, no different between `.attr("disabled","disabled"); ` and `.prop("disabled",true); ` Also OP code working is fine, better delete your post before getting `down vote`

Comment: yep, still he said his code is not working, so that i ask him to change syntax

Comment: For sure, problem is something else, not this syntax because the code working here.

Comment: Actually i am not passing the <option> here. <option> values are stored in another js file.. I will edit my question